# EF eager load multiple child child collections

Tags: entity-framework

I can't seem to find how to eager load multiple child child collections in EF. So I can do:

```
blawConext.Blaws
    .Include(b => b.ChildCollection
             .Select(cc => cc.ChildChildCollection)
     )
```

I can even go deeper and deeper without a problem but I can't get the umm peer? collection, The below does not work

```
blawConext.Blaws
    .Include(b => b.ChildCollection
             .Select(cc => cc.ChildChildCollection1)
             .Select(cc => cc.ChildChildCollection2)
     )
```

Comment: The only way I've found that seems to work is to use two Includes with duplicate paths except for the end. So one full include branching all the way down to ChildChildCollection1, and then a second include exactly the same but with ChildChildCollection2, but that seems wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify multiple includes:

```
blawConext.Blaws
    .Include(b => b.ChildCollection.Select(cc => cc.ChildChildCollection1))
    .Include(b => b.ChildCollection.Select(cc => cc.ChildChildCollection2))
```

Comment: Dang I was hoping for something more elegant, I have a lot of Includes to add, Thanks though!