# Error loading multiple grandchild collections with include using EF 6 and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm trying to load multiple grandchild collections to my object.

```
    using (var context = GetContext())
    {
        return await context.Collection.Where(c => c.Id == id)
            .Include(a => a.Child.Select(b => b.GrandChildCollection1))
            .Include(a => a.Child.Select(b => b.GrandChildCollection2))
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

According to [EF eager load multiple child child collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760475/ef-eager-load-multiple-child-child-collections) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604899/5903172 my code should work but I'm getting the following error:

> "Unknown column 'Extent1.Id' in 'on clause'"

This guy seem to have had the same issue [MySQL Unknown column 'Extent1.ID' in 'on clause' with EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427561/mysql-unknown-column-extent1-id-in-on-clause-with-ef6)

Anybody got any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: The question you linked to doesn't have basic information like the table schemas, context configuration and the generated query. The query is generated by the database provider. MySQL's own Connector/.NET has several issues and people use other providers like [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/). Depending on the EF version you use you can log the generated SQL statements. In EF 6.2 you can do it by assigning a stream object to `DbContext.Database.Log`, eg `context.Database.Log=Console.Out`.